# External js file not working with HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I am building a website which this page uses an external javascript file, one of the main function is that in the form if the user does not enter anything or enter the wrong value and clicks on the submit button, a error message will show up above each section, but unfortunately mine when I click on the submit button it will still submit and will not show any error, I suspect that the Javascript file is not linked properly but I did set the path correctly as you can see in the picture and the  on the HTML page.

[image: Path of the javascript file]

HTML File:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="Demonstrates some basic HTML content elements and CSS" />
<meta name="keywords" content="html, css" />
<meta name="author" content="Jordan Siow"  />

<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "styles/style.css"/>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="scripts/apply.js"></script>

<title>Apply </title>
```

```
<section class="front_title">

    <p> Company XIT <a href="index.html"><img src="styles/images/logo.png" alt="logo" height="70" width="250"/></a>
    </p>

</section>

<section class="topnav">

    <table>
        <tr>
            

            <td >
                <a href="index.html">Main</a>
            </td>

            <td >
                <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
            </td>

            <td id="current">
                <a href="apply.html">Apply</a>
            </td>

            <td>
                <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </td>

            <td>
                <a href="enhancements2.html">Enhancements</a>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</section>
```

```
<section id="style_apply">

    <h2>Submit your Application!</h2>

    <form method="post" id="apply_form" action="https://mercury.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php">
        <p><span id="job_id_error" class="error"></span></p>
        <p><label for="jobid">Job Reference Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="jobid" id="jobid" maxlength="5" pattern="[0-9]{5}" /></p>

        <p><span id="firstname_error" class="error"></span></p>
        <p><label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        <input type ="text" name="First Name" id="firstname" maxlength="20" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" /></p>

        <p><span id="lastname_error" class="error"></span></p>
        <p><label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        <input type ="text" name="Last Name" id="lastname" maxlength="20" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" /></p>
        <br/>

        <p><span id="dob_error" class="error"></span></p>
        <p><label for="dateofbirth">Date of Birth</label>
        <input type="date" name="Date of Birth" id="dateofbirth" /></p>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        
        <label>Gender</label>
        <p><span id="gender_error" class="error"></span></p>
        <fieldset id="gender">
            <label for="male">Male</label>
            <input type="radio" id="male" name="Gender"  value="male" />
            <label for="female">Female</label>
            <input type="radio" id="female" name="Gender" value="female"/>
            <label for="other">Others</label>
            <input type="radio" id="other" name="Gender" value="other"/>
            <label for="rathernotsay">Rather Not Say</label>
            <input type="radio" id="rathernotsay" name="Gender" value="rathernotsay"/>
        </fieldset>
        <br/>

        <div id="fieldset_label">
            <label>Address Information</label>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
            <p><span id="streetaddress_error" class="error"></span></p>
            <p><label for="streetaddress">Street address</label>
            <input type="text" name="Address" id="streetaddress" maxlength="40" "/></p>

            <p><span id="suburb_error" class="error"></span></p>
            <p><label for="suburb">Suburb/town</label>
            <input type="text" name= "Suburb" id="suburb" maxlength="40" /></p>

            <p><span id="state_error" class="error"></span></p>
            <p><label for="state">State</label>
            <select  id="state" name="State">
                <option value="">Please select</option>
                <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
                <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
                <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
                <option value="NT">NT</option>
                <option value="WA">WA</option>
                <option value="SA">SA</option>
                <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
                <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
            </select></p>

            <p><span id="postcodr_error" class="error"></span></p>
            <p><label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
            <input type="text" name= "Postcode" id="postcode" maxlength="4" pattern="\d{4}"  placeholder="Postcode"/></p>
        </fieldset>
        <br/>

        <p><span id="email_error" class="error"></span></p>
        <p><label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="Email Address" id="email" /></p>

        <p><span id="phonenumber_error" class="error"></span></p>
        <p><label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="Phone Number" id="phonenumber" maxlength="12" pattern="[0-9]{8-12}" ></p>

        <label>Skill list</label>
        <fieldset>
            <p><span id="skill_error" class="error"></span></p>
            <label for="skill1">Web development languages</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="skill1" name="Skill 1" value="skill"/>
            <label for="skill2">Data Management abilities</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="skill2" name="Skill 2" value="skill"/>
            <label for="skill3">Others</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="skill3" name="Other" value="skill"/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <section>
                <label for="comm" style="display:block">Other skillset</label>
                <textarea class="comments" id="comm" name="Comments" rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Other skillsets..."></textarea>
             </section>
        </fieldset>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <div class="align_center">
            <p><span id="error_check" class="error"></span></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Application"/>
            <input type="reset" value="Reset Application form"/>
        </div>

    </form>
</section>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<footer class = "footer_text">
    <hr/>
    <p>
        <strong>&#169;</strong>
        <a class="footer_text" href="http://www.swinburne.edu.au/">
            Swinburne Universty of Technology
        </a>
    </p>

    <p>  &#160;
        &#160;
        <strong>Done by:</strong> <a class="footer_text" href="mailto:103173691@student.swin.edu.au">
            Jordan Siow</a>
    </p>

</footer>
```

JS File:

```
/* To Validate the Form */

function validate(){
    // Initialises the result variable
    var result = true;

    // Intialises the error tags
    var job_id_error = document.getElementById("job_id_error");
    job_id_error.innerHTML = "";
    var firstname_error = document.getElementById("firstname_error");
    firstname_error.innerHTML = "";
    var lastname_error = document.getElementById("lastname_error");
    lastname_error.innerHTML = "";
    var dob_error = document.getElementById("dob_error");
    dob_error.innerHTML = "";
    var gender_error = document.getElementById("gender_error");
    gender_error.innerHTML = "";
    var streetaddress_error = document.getElementById("streetaddress_error");
    streetaddress_error.innerHTML = "";
    var suburb_error = document.getElementById("suburb_error");
    suburb_error.innerHTML = "";
    var state_error = document.getElementById("state_error");
    state_error.innerHTML = "";
    var postcode_error = document.getElementById("postcode_error");
    postcode_error.innerHTML = "";
    var email_error = document.getElementById("email_error");
    email_error.innerHTML = "";
    var phonenumber_error = document.getElementById("phonenumber_error");
    phonenumber_error.innerHTML = "";
    var skill_error = document.getElementById("skill_error");
    skill_error.innerHTML = ""


    // If there is an error in the input it will set the result to false and displays an error message
    // To get the variables from the form and will chgeck the given rules

    var jobid = document.getElementById("jobid").value;
    if (jobid == ""){
        job_id_error.innerHTML = "Job Reference Number must not be blank";
        result = false;
    }

    var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    if (!firstname.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/) || firstname.value == ""){
        firstname_error.innerHTML = "First name must only contain alphabetic characters";
        alert("First name must only contain alphabetic characters")
        result = false;
    }

    var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    if (!lastname.match(/^[a-zA-Z\-]+$/) || lastname.value == ""){
        lastname_error.innerHTML = "Last name must only contain aphabetic characters";
        result = false;
    }

    var dateofbirth = document.getElementById("dateofbirth").value;
    if (!dateofbirth.match(/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/)){
        dob_error.innerHTML = "Invalid Date of Birth";
        result = false;
    }

    var age = calculate_age(dateofbirth);
    if (!isFinite(age) || isNaN(age)) {
        dob_error.innerHTML = "Your Date of Birth role is not Available.";
        result = false;
    }
    else if (age < 21 || age > 70) {
        dob_error.innerHTML =
            "You must be between 21 and 70 years old to apply.";
        result = false;
    }

    var male = document.getElementById("male").checked;
    var female = document.getElementById("female").checked;
    var other = document.getElementById("other").checked;
    var rathernotsay = document.getElementById("rathernotsay").checked;
    if (!(male || female || other || rathernotsay)) {
        gender_error.innerHTML = "Please select a gender.";
        result = false;
    }

    var streetaddress = document.getElementById("streetaddress").value;
    if (streetaddress == "") {
        streetaddress_error.innerHTML = "You must enter a street address.";
        result = false;
    }

    var suburb = document.getElementById("suburb").value;
    if (suburb == "") {
        suburb_error.innerHTML = "You must enter a suburb or town";
        result = false;
    }

    var postcode = Number(document.getElementById("postcode").value);
    if (postcode == "") {
        postcode_error.innerHTML = "You must select a postcode";
        result = false;
    }

    var state = document.getElementById("state").value
    if (state == "") {
        state_error.innerHTML = "You must select a state";
        result = false;
    } else {
        var tempMsg = validate_postcode(state, postcode);
        if (tempMsg != "") {
            state_error.innerHTML = tempMsg;
            result = false;
        }
    }

    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    if (email == "") {
        email_error.innerHTML = "You must enter an email address";
        result = false;
    }

    var phonenumber = document.getElementById("phonenumber").value;
    if (phonenumber == "") {
        phonenumber_error.innerHTML = "You must enter a phone number";
        result = false;
    }

    if (result){
        storeBooking(firstname, lastname, dateofbirth, male, female, other, rathernotsay, streetaddress, suburb, state, postcode, email, phonnumber)
    }

    if (!result) {
        document.getElementById("error_check").innerHTML = "Please correct all of the errors given above.";
    }

    return result;

}

/**
 * calcualte age from date of birth
 */
function calculate_age(dateofbirth) {
    var today = new Date();
    var DateOfBirth = new Date(dateofbirth);
    // get the difference between the years
    var age = today.getFullYear() - DateOfBirth.getFullYear();
    // get the difference between the months
    var month = today.getMonth() - DateOfBirth.getMonth();
    // if the dateofbirth month and day is earlier in the year
    if (month < 0 || (month === 0 && today.getDate() < DateOfBirth.getDate())) {
        age--; // remove a year
    }
    return age;
}

function validate_postcode(state, postcode) {
    var errMsg = "";
    switch (state) {
        case "vic":
            if (!((postcode >= 3000 && postcode <= 3999) || (postcode >= 8000 && postcode <= 8999))) {
                errMsg += "Post Code not in Victoria.";
            }
            break;
        case "nsw":
            if (!((postcode >= 1000 && postcode <= 2599) || (postcode >= 2619 && postcode <= 2899) || (postcode >= 2921 && postcode <= 2999))) {
                errMsg += "Post Code not in New South Wales.";
            }
            break;
        case "qld":
            if (!((postcode >= 4000 && postcode <= 4999) || (postcode >= 9000 && postcode <= 9999))) {
                errMsg += "Post Code not in Queensland.";
            }
            break;
        case "nt":
            if (!(postcode >= 800 && postcode <= 999)) {
                errMsg += "Post Code not in Northern Territory.";
            }
            break;
        case "wa":
            if (!(postcode >= 6000 && postcode <= 6999)) {
                errMsg += "Post Code not in Western Australia.";
            }
            break;
        case "sa":
            if (!(postcode >= 5000 && postcode <= 5999)) {
                errMsg += "Post Code not in Southern Australia.";
            }
            break;
        case "tas":
            if (!(postcode >= 7000 && postcode <= 7999)) {
                errMsg += "Post Code not in Tasmania.";
            }
            break;
        case "act":
            if (!((postcode >= 200 && postcode <= 299) || (postcode >= 2600 && postcode <= 2618) || (postcode >= 2900 && postcode <= 2920))) {
                errMsg += "Post Code not in Australian Capital Territory.";
            }
            break;
        default:
            errMsg = "Post Code not Valid.";
    }
    return errMsg;
}

/**
 * Prefill the form from exisitng session data
 */
function prefill_id() {
    var jobId_input = document.getElementById("jobid");
    if (localStorage.jobId != undefined) {
        // hidden input to submit details
        jobId_input.value = localStorage.jobId;
        jobId_input.readOnly = true;
    } else {
        jobId_input.readOnly = false;
    }
}

/**
 * Prefill the form from exisitng session data
 */
function prefill_form() {
    prefill_id();
    if (sessionStorage.firstname != undefined) {
        document.getElementById("firstname").value = sessionStorage.firstname;
        document.getElementById("lastname").value = sessionStorage.lastname;
        document.getElementById("dateofbirth").value = sessionStorage.dateofbirth;
        document.getElementById("streetaddress").value = sessionStorage.streetaddress;
        document.getElementById("suburb").value = sessionStorage.suburb;
        document.getElementById("state").value = sessionStorage.state;
        document.getElementById("postcode").value = sessionStorage.postcode;
        document.getElementById("email").value = sessionStorage.email;
        document.getElementById("phonenumber").value = sessionStorage.phonenumber;

        switch (sessionStorage.gender) {
            case "male":
                document.getElementById("male").checked = true;
                break;
            case "female":
                document.getElementById("female").checked = true;
                break;
            case "other":
                document.getElementById("other").checked = true;
                break;
            case "rathernotsay":
                document.getElementById("rathernotsay").checked = true;
                break;
        }
        var skills = sessionStorage.skills;
        document.getElementById("skill1").checked = skills.includes("skill1");
        document.getElementById("skill2").checked = skills.includes("skill2");
        document.getElementById("skill3").checked = skills.includes("skill3");
    }
}

/**
 * Store Job ID for pre fill in application form
 */
function storeJobId1() {
    localStorage.jobId = document.getElementById("job1_id").innerHTML;
}
function storeJobId2() {
    localStorage.jobId = document.getElementById("job2_id").innerHTML;
}

/**
 * Store values for session
 */
function storeBooking(skill1, skill2, skill3, comm, firstname,
    lastname, dateofbirth, streetaddress, suburb, state, postcode, email, phonenumber, male, female, other) {
    // store values in sessionStorage
    var skill_string = "";
    if (skill1) {
        skill_string = "skill1";
    }
    if (skill2) {
        if (skill_string != "") {
            skill_string += ", ";
        }
        skill_string += "skill2";
    }
    if (skill3) {
        if (skill_string != "") {
            skill_string += ", ";
        }
        skill_string += "skill3";
    }
    sessionStorage.skills = skill_string;

    sessionStorage.firstname = firstname;
    sessionStorage.lastname = lastname;
    sessionStorage.dateofbirth = dateofbirth;
    sessionStorage.streetaddress = streetaddress;
    sessionStorage.suburb = suburb;
    sessionStorage.state = state;
    sessionStorage.postcode = ;
    sessionStorage.email = email;
    sessionStorage.phonenumber = phonenumber;
    sessionStorage.comm = comm;
    if (male) {
        sessionStorage.gender = "male";
    } else if (female) {
        sessionStorage.gender = "female";
    } else if (other) {
        sessionStorage.gender = "other";
    } else if (rathernotsay) {
        sessionStorage.gender = "rathernotsay";
    }

}

/*
 This function is called when the browser window loads
 it will register functions that will respond to browser events
*/
function init() {
    if (document.title == "Available Jobs") {
        document.getElementById("job1_apply").onclick = storeJobId1;
        document.getElementById("job2_apply").onclick = storeJobId2;
    } else if (document.title == "Application Form") {
        prefill_form();
        // register the event listener to the form
        document.getElementById("apply_form").onsubmit = validate;
        document.getElementById("apply_form").onreset = function () {
            localStorage.clear();
            prefill_id();
        ;}
    }
}

window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out this article: [preventDefault() Event Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp)

When clicked, you should prevent the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="scripts/apply.js"></script>
```

Add the above script tag just before closing of body tag, it it best practice.

put a `console.log("js file linked");` inside js file to test whether its linked or not.

Feel free to ask if it didn't work...

Comment: Hey Anish, sorry to ask what do you mean by "Add the above script tag just before closing of body tag" ?

Comment: i mean put <script> tag

Comment: So I put the script tase right before closing the body tag unfortunately it still does not work

Comment: Just a side info: The above declaration is deprecated. The new one for HTML 5 is `<script type="application/javascript" src=""></script>`

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you mentioned

> my friend told me its got to do with the last line in the js file "window.onload = init();

Your friend is correct - not sure if this is the only relevant thing, but here you are first running the function `init()` and the return value of that function is being saved into window.onload. Check out this example code:

```
function init() {
    console.log(document.readyState);
}
window.onload = init();
console.log("Window onload is", window.onload);
```

Here init is run immediately and the return value of init will be saved to window.onload. This prints

```
loading
apply.js:315 Window onload is null
```

Instead, you should add a *reference* to the init function, so that the value of window.onload is your init function itself, not the return value; so the correction would be

```
function init() {
    console.log(document.readyState);
}
window.onload = init;
console.log("Window onload is", window.onload);
// this one prints out
// Window onload is ƒ init() {console.log(document.readyState);}
// apply.js:311 complete
```

The "document.readyState" is used to check if the document has been loaded and parsed.

Comment: The job1_apply is in my other html page , agree with you , debugging is extremely important especially in this case right now

Comment: Ah, I see! So could it be that your script is running on the HTML page without job1_apply then? That should give you some kind of error in the console, so I am not sure if that is _really_ the root cause of the issue :)

 Is the page public or in github where we could see it?

Comment: Unfortunately even looking into the console it didn't show up any error, my friend told me its got to do with the last line in the js file "window.onload = init();", but I do not understand the cause of it, and yeap I do have it uploaded! https://github.com/JordanSYY/assgn2

Comment: @KeKDee Oh yeah I see it now, your friend is on to something! I edited my answer.

Comment: Ohh yes? which part did you manage to change and fix?

Comment: @KeKDee I edited my answer and added the details of what I found there :)

Comment: Sorry im actually new to GitHub haha, how do I view your changes that you've made? my bad